# What Jersey doesn't like in my Stateless Session Bean?

Tags: java, ejb, jersey, jax-rs

This is my SLSB:

```
@Stateless(name = "FinderEJB")
@Path("/")
public class Finder implements FinderLocal {
  @Path("/simple")
  @GET
  public String simple() {
    return "works";
  }
}
```

The interface is:

```
@Local
public interface FinderLocal {
  public String simple();
}
```

This is what I'm getting in Glassfish server log when I'm trying to open the url `/simple`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:156)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:208)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:740)
[...]
```

What is it about? I managed to find a topic about it [at nabble.com](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/SessionBean-with-interface-causes-java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-object-is-not-an-instance-of-de-td4914858.html), but it has no solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Glassfish (in its default installation) doesn't support EJB 3.1. You have [to upgrade it](http://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/ejb_3_1_in_glassfish) in order to get such a support.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing EJB / JAX-RS, with an interface and an implementation, i had these error too :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

It failed with glassfish V3 and 3.1, but it works well with tomcat 7 / jersey 1.5

I submit a bug with the test case :
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16199

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; it turned out it was a configuration error in web.xml.

Be sure to use something like:

`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.company.product.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>`

Hope it helped

Comment: Of course my `web.xml` is configured properly. Without SLSB annotations the class works fine and is exposed in JAX-RS.